# Safe to call File.ReadAllText() on binary files?

Tags: .net, regex, file, text, io

I am writing a little program that iterates through all files in a directory and searches for a substring.
It's basically something like this:

```
s = File.ReadAllText(FileName)
If s.Contains("Find this substring") Then
    MatchesFound += 1
End If
```

I also have a Regex version of this program, but still using File.ReadAllText() to read the files.

Should I be concerned with calling File.ReadAllText() on binary files?
I don't mind getting a few false positives in the search results, but I don't want my program to crash.
MSDN docs don't show any exceptions for this method that result from not being able to read or interpret file data.

Comment: You may want to change this to check individual lines in a loop instead of using `ReadAllText`. You gain two benefits: more predictable memory usage (large files will not consume all of RAM) and you will increase performance as you can stop processing as soon as you find the string (`ReadAllText` will always read an entire file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program won't crash. If the file is too long, it might just take up lot of memory. ReadAllText releases file handle before returning to you. As such, your handles would get properly disposed.

Your string will just have text representation of the binary file. Most of it probably would be invalid characters. Framework internally uses unicode for string (UTF16).

Only thing you should be concerned about is extremely large files, e.g. a 4GB ISO file. If you have files that big in your directory then you should probably make better algorithm to make code efficient instead of blindly getting ReadAllText.

Also, before you read, you can check file size; and if its obvious that its a pure binary file (for ex. 100MB zip file); you can skip that and move to next.

Comment: It will crash if the file is too big (out of memory).

Comment: Yes, that is correct. But [ReadAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368.aspx) itself doesn't throw OutOfMemoryException. It will come from system/framework while file is being loaded into memory.

Comment: Yet, you still cannot say that "your program won't crash". Also, if  this  is to be general purpose usage and/or may in fact read very large files then the OP should use a slightly more complex algorithm that has a more predictable memory usage pattern - that is use a loop and read individual lines and do the comparison on each one. There is nothing to be gained performance wise using `ReadAllText` over reading a single line if the reader class is using proper buffering.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work.
Calling the method ReadAllText returns a String. Therefore, even if the format is not the good one, you will still end up with String.

The method itself is supposed to throw exception for file related issues; not for String format issues.

The only problem I could think of is if you try to open a file which is too large to fit in your memory, an exception will be thrown. Otherwise, your code should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `ReadAllText` depends on a guessed file encoding. Strings in binary files could be stored in any encoding, without being guessable because of the binary file's header. Also note that binary files could store correctly encoded strings in a way that makes the reader not decode the string properly, for example because a UTF-16 string starts at an odd position in the file. And if the reader guesses UTF-8 encoding, there's even room for encoding errors that possibly cause the first character of the string to be decoded as garbage.

Comment: Thanks. My intention was to discard any binary files from the search results later, manually. The search results being a list of file names whose contents match the text pattern.